# SQL Query with JOIN and PIVOT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

in my project I have two tables and one pivot table an I want to get my expected result with one SQL Query if possible.

Here my tables:

**table_1**

```
id | title         | description
-----------------------------------------------
1  | restaurant_1  | lorem ipsum
2  | restaurant_2  | lorem ipsum
3  | restaurant_3  | lorem ipsum
```

**table_2**

```
id | title    | description   | src
-----------------------------------------------
1  | image_1  | lorem ipsum   | url/
2  | image_2  | lorem ipsum   | url/
3  | image_3  | lorem ipsum   | url/
```

**table_1_2**

```
id | restaurant_id    | image_id
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 1                | 1
2  | 2                | 2
3  | 2                | 3
4  | 3                | 2
```

I push my result to an array and json_encode(array) with PHP:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  // Add results to array
  $restaurants = [];

  while($result_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($restaurants, $result_arr);
  }

  // close connection
  mysqli_close($link);

  // return json
  echo json_encode($restaurants);
```

Then I expect the following result:

```
restaurants = [{
   'id': 1,
   'title': 'restaurant_1'
   'description': 'lorem ipsum'
   'images': [{'id': 1, 'description': 'lorem ipsum', 'src': 'url/'}]
  },{
   'id': 2,
   'title': 'restaurant_2'
   'description': 'lorem ipsum'
   'images': [{'id': 2, 'description': 'lorem ipsum', 'src': 'url/'},
              {'id': 3, 'description': 'lorem ipsum', 'src': 'url/'}]  
  },{
   'id': 3,
   'title': 'restaurant_3'
   'description': 'lorem ipsum'
   'images': [{'id': 2, 'description': 'lorem ipsum', 'src': 'url/'}]
 }];
```

All my attempts to get the expected results return me an empty array.

I hope some one of you have an idea and can help me with this problem.

Greetings Lars

Comment: Are you trying to generate JSON using SQL? Or do you have a library which gets SQL records and convert them to JSON?

Comment: Hi, I have no library. I use PHP and push my result to an array and encode the array with json_encode()